# db.collection.update( ) all documents

Tags: mongodb, rename

I try rename one field in all documents of a collection, with

```
db.coll.update({},{ $rename: {'originField':'newField'} });
```

but only one document is changed, why ?

Comment: by default updates are singular, you need to add `,{multi:true}` as a third param

Comment: @Sammaye you can add the comment like a answer to close ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: update every document on one field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038547/mongodb-update-every-document-on-one-field)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

All updates in MongoDB are, by default, singular. You must add a third option to your command to make:

```
db.coll.update({},{ $rename: {'originField':'newField'} }, {multi:true});
```

If you are using 3.2 and above you can use `updateMany()`:

```
db.coll.updateMany({}, {$rename: {'originField': "newField"}})
```

Comment: Here is the reference from MongoDB documentation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#update-multiple-documents

Comment: Since MongoDB 3.2 you can also [use `updateMany`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038593/1494454).

Answer (score 4):

```
db.collectionname.update( { "field" : "oldvalue" }, { $set:{ "field" : "newvalue" } }, { multi : true } );
```

Comment: How to do it for  oldvalue+"some string"

Answer (score 2):

Since MongoDB 3.2, you can use this shorter syntax:

`db.coll.updateMany({}, {$rename: {'originField': "newField"}})`