# Loopback: Adding new field with default value, how to all documents in mongoDB is updated

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback

I am using Loopback 3 and mongoDB

I add new field with default value in json model

```
  {
    "name": "myModel",
    "options": {
        "mongodb": {
          "collection": "MyModel"
        }
    },
    "mixins": {
       "ShareApi": {
        "allow": ["findById"]
      }
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "name"
      },
      "newField": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "default": false
      }
    }
  }
```

However, this just work for new documents. How to old documents are updated with newfield

Comment: You can do it with an aggregation pipeline update, $set and $ifNull.

Comment: @D.SM does Loopback support this migration? I want to achieve this from Loopback, not  mongoDB

Comment: Don't know about that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: update every document on one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038547/mongodb-update-every-document-on-one-field)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update all documents then use updateAll query of loopback:

```
myModel.updateAll({}, { newField: true }, function (err, affected) { })
```