# How to update multiple items in array with multiple values

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document schema:

```js
let document = {
    _id: 'a1',
    name: 'some_name',
    items: [{
            _id: 1,
            name: 'item1',
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'item2',
        },
        {
            _id: 3,
            name: 'item3',
        },
        {
            _id: 4,
            name: 'item4',
        },
    ]
}
```

and the following update payload is a list of documents

```js
let updates = [{
        _id: 1,
        name: 'item11',
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        name: 'item22',
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        name: 'item33',
    },
    {
        _id: 4,
        name: 'item44',
    },
]
```

I want to update each item in the collection with the item in the update payload that has the same `_id`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a too specific update related to each unique `_id` (So [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) will not work - this is not "many" each `_id` is unique). Maybe related:
[MongoDB: update every document on one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038547/mongodb-update-every-document-on-one-field)

In your case, it is like running 4 times `updateOne` (And each time change the name to some value).

One option is to use `bulkWrite`:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/

```
db.myCollection.bulkWrite([
      { updateOne : {
         "filter" : { "_id" : "1" },
         "update" : { $set : { "name" : "item11" } }
      },
      { updateOne : {
         "filter" : { "_id" : "2" },
         "update" : { $set : { "name" : "item22" } }
      }
]);
```

The other option is to use plain Javascript (And [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [for](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_iteration.asp)) and for each item in the array `updateOne`.

Outline only (You should test this concept under MongoDB playground).

```
updates.map(function(item) {
  console.log(item._id); // 1 2 3 4
  console.log(item.name); // item11 item22 item33 item44
  db.myCollection.updateOne(
    { "_id" : item._id  }, /* filter */
    { $set: { "_id" : item.name } } /* update */
  );
})
```

Comment: I suppose one could use javascript to build the payload for `bulkWrite` then use it