# Update multiples fields Mongo DB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, request, updates

i have a big problem with mongo db because i want to update a multiple fields with One request.

My Json is :

```
    db.test.findOne();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51e7dd16d2f8db27b56ea282"),
        "ad" : "noc2",
        "list" : {
                "p45" : {
                        "id" : "p45",
                        "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T12:18:30.568Z"),
                        "value3" : 21,
                        "value1" : 100,
                        "value2" : 489
                },
                "p6" : {
                        "id" : "p6"
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-07-18T12:18:30.568Z"),
                        "value3" : 21,
                        "value1" : 100,
                        "value2" : 489
                },
                "p4578" : {
                       "id" : "4578"
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-07-18T12:18:30.568Z"),
                        "value3" : 21,
                        "value1" : 100,
                        "value2" : 489
                }
        }
}
```

I want created a field createdDate for all elements list , if createdDate field doesn't exist or is null.

A request example, what i use for update one field with upsert true in my code java :

```
 db.people.update({"advertiser":"noc2","list.4578.createdDate":{$exists:false}},{$set:{"list.p4578.createdDate":"08/08/08"}});
```

I tried with java  where list.4578 is replaced by variable but is too long for too much fields. If i have 100 fields, i do execute 100 requests.

Look :

```
public void createdFirstDateField(MongoAccess mongo, String ad,HashMap<String,Object> hfirstDate){



    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();


    Iterator <String> it = hfirstDate.keySet().iterator();
    String key="";

    while (it.hasNext()){

    key=it.next();
    searchQuery.append("ad", ad).append(key, new BasicDBObject("$exists", false));

    //System.out.println(key);
    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject ();
    doc.append("$set",new BasicDBObject(key,new Date()));
    mongo.insert(searchQuery, doc); // update with upsert true


    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [update with upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-operations-with-the-upsert-flag)?

```
db.people.update({"advertiser": "noc2"},
                 {$set: {"list.$.createdDate": "08/08/08"}},
                 {$upsert: true);
```

If the `createdDate` exists it will be updated, if not it will be inserted.

Comment: Yes, i tried this but is not good because i want update all fields if the createdDate is null only and your solution update all time the createdDate field. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can update multiple documents at once, [using update Multi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740023/mongodb-how-to-update-multiple-documents-with-a-single-command). But there in not atomic way to update multiple embedded documents.

You can checkout mongodb positional operator, but this does not fit in your use case.