# Collection only updates once?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to do two updates to my collection using Meteor/Mongo. But it seems to only update one of them. I've checked the Mongo docs, it seems to be correct, how come it doesn't register both?

```
Teams.update(myTeam,
            {$inc: {points: -score}},
            {$pull: {members: myMembers[who]}}
            );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How to update multiple documents with a single command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740023/mongodb-how-to-update-multiple-documents-with-a-single-command)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing your second update command as the third parameter to the update function, instead of passing as another value in the second parameter.

```
Teams.update(myTeam,
        {$inc: {points: -score},
        $pull: {members: myMembers[who]}}
        );
```

Comment: Icic! Weird, the docs seem to put it that way, or I read it wrongly. =(
Anyways, it works great! Thanks Brian! =)