# Mongodb - Pull an element in an array to all documents which contains that element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I've a schema like this:

```
orders = {"productIds:[1,2]}

products = {"_id": 1}
```

I want to pull the value `1` (for example) in the array `productIds` to all `orders` that contains this value.
I've tried with:

```
db.orders.update({productIds: {$elemMatch: {$eq: 1}}},{$pull: {productIds: 1}})
```

but this query updates only one document that has the value 1 in productIds, not all documents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How to update multiple documents with a single command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740023/mongodb-how-to-update-multiple-documents-with-a-single-command)

Answer (score 2):

you have to specify to update multiple documents.

```
db.orders.update({productIds: {$elemMatch: {$eq: 1}}},{$pull: {productIds: 1}},{multi:true})
```

Comment: This question has been asked and answer many many ... many times before. Please don't duplicate an answer. You shouldn't answer such question unless it provides additional details or new method to solve the problem. Instead you should flag the question as [Possible duplicate of MongoDB: How to update multiple documents with a single command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740023/mongodb-how-to-update-multiple-documents-with-a-single-command)

Comment: OP had a very specific question to $pull with arrays, which is dominantly different than generally updating multiple docs. I don't believe the commenter above read OP.