# How expensive is using addToSet with $in

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

It is my first MongoDB project am still in the design phase of my System so I want to know if I am designing it right.

I want to know if it is possible to use addToSet method with $in selector and if it is, how expensive is that?

For example, I have some data like this:

```
{
    {
     Id:1,
     Groups: ["Group1", "Group2"],
     Events:["event1"]
    },
    {
     Id:2,
     Groups: ["Group2" ],
     Events:["event2"]
    },
    ,
    {
     Id:3,
     Groups: ["Group1","Group3" ],
     Events:["event1"]
    },
}
```

Is it possible to call it like below and how expensive is that?

```
db.test.update(
  { Groups: { $in: ["Group1"] } },
   { $addToSet: {Events: [ "newEvent1", "newEvent2" ] } }
)
```

- P.S: I would assume that in short time I will end up with millions of records and in the worst case scenario 1 million rows can belong to a group.

*P.S.S: Since the query is on a list property, should I add an index or something? Is it even a correct way to go?

### Update

Maybe I am using the wrong selector, but I just want to update the rows that have the group1 in their groups. So the results expected to be like this:

```
{
    {
     Id:1,
     Groups: ["Group1", "Group2"],
     Events:["event1", "newEvent1", "newEvent2"]
    },
    {
     Id:2,
     Groups: ["Group2" ],
     Events:["event2"]
    },
    ,
    {
     Id:3,
     Groups: ["Group1","Group3" ],
     Events:["event1","newEvent1", "newEvent2"]
    },
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [MongoDB: How to update multiple documents with a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740023/mongodb-how-to-update-multiple-documents-with-a-single-command)

Comment: @NeilLunn It is not a duplicate of that question. I even wrote the command that I expect to work based on MongoDB 3.4 documentation. My question is if I am designing my system correctly and if this way of doing it is too expensive when I will have a huge amount of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Expensive" is a relative term, and also depends on other things, such as:

- The provisioned hardware (CPU, RAM, etc.)
- Your deployment topology (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster)
- How large the query will be (how many terms in the `$in` and the `$addToSet`)
- Other factors

Unfortunately there is no single, easy answer to these questions, as many of them are very workload-dependent. Also, the query you posted is only one out of surely many others that you need.

Having said that, slow queries in MongoDB are typically caused by:

- Underprovisioned hardware
- Sub-optimal indexes (too few indexes, too many indexes, indexes don't have enough coverage, etc.)
- Sub-optimal schema design for the workload

The only way to know if your planned queries are too expensive or not is to check out their `explain()` output, and see if there's any obvious improvements that can be made, such as the existence of `COLLSCAN` stages, small number of returned documents compared to examined documents (which means that the query is not targeted enough).

You may find these links usually contain enough information about optimization:

- [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design: Part 1](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)
- [Part 2](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2)
- [Part 3](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3)
- [Data Models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/)
- [Use Cases](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/)
- [Query Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/)
- [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/)

Once the queries are optimized, then it's time to put a simulated workload on the app & database, and monitor its performance using tools such as:

- [mongotop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongotop/)
- [mongostat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/)

and confirm that you provisioned enough hardware for the workload you're expecting to see.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The articles helped me a lot to understand whats going on in MongoDB