# Update the second... document mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I query my mongodb collection with a query I get multiple documents found.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) , "*the update() method updates a single document*". And I cannot use the *multi:true* option, since I want to update the different documents found with different values so:

I would like to do the following:

1. Update the **first** document with :

> ```
> db.collection('foo').update(query,{$set : {'qux':'bar'}})
> ```

2. Update the **second** document with

> ```
> db.collection('foo').update(query,{$set : {'qux':'blep'}})
> ```

Close to this, but not quite getting there
[MongoDB: How to update multiple documents with a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740023/mongodb-how-to-update-multiple-documents-with-a-single-command)

[Worth reading :)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3092.txt)

Comment: Why not add extra conditions to the query? e.g. {qux: {$nin: ["bar", "foo"]}}

Comment: That would mean that I need to know what not to include in my $nin... Hmmm but of course this could work with some workaround since I know what I want to update to.