# MongoDB increment all values of a key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am very new to mongoDB.

i have this collection here:

{ 
name: Peter 
salary: 3000
}, 
{
name: Marry
salary: 2000 
}, 
{
name: Sally
salary: 1000 
}

What should I do if I want to increase all salaries by 500?

I tried db.bounties.update({},{$inc: { salary: 500}}) but only the first one got updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: How to update multiple documents with a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740023/mongodb-how-to-update-multiple-documents-with-a-single-command)

Answer (score 3):

there're two ways

1- use updateMany it means Updates all documents that match the specified filter for a collection

`db.bounties.updateMany({},{$inc: { salary: 500}})`

2- use update with `multi` parameter

`db.bounties.update({},{$inc: { salary: 500}},{multi:true})`