# mongodb replace string in all documents

Tags: mongodb

I have an existing mongo collection. Each document inside looks similar to this:

document1:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "subId": 11,
  ...
}
```

document2:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "subId": 11,
  ...
}
```

...

```
documenntN:
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "subId": 11,
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to run a db.collection.update query in such a way as I can replace the "subId": 11 to "subId": 22?

output:

document1:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "subId": 22,
  ...
}
```

document2:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "subId": 22,
  ...
}
```

...

documenntN:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "subId": 22,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: How to update multiple documents with a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740023/mongodb-how-to-update-multiple-documents-with-a-single-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.collection.updateMany({ subId: 11 }, { $set: { subId: 22 } })`